# Why the space of all permutations of a vector (n!) is smaller than the space of all possible permutations of a sorting network?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, sorting, network

Imagine you have a vector with 2048 entries. The total permutations are 2048! Now you have a sorting network let us say AKS, the total number of possible results with nlog(n) gates is $2^ {n log (n)}$ and that is excluding the constants. Which is much larger than 2048!

So what happens with all these extra possible results? Do they give me a valid result? Moreover, if they are just several ways to solve the same permutation, which one is selected. And are they uniformly distributed???

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is, but perhaps you would find it helpful to work through the 6 permutations of 3 elements with a 3-gate sorting network.

Comment: @PeterTaylor so u have nlog(n)*c possible solutions with AKS and even nlog(n)*log(n) for Batchers network.. and only n! permutations. what happens with all the extra solutions?

Comment: If you have a 3-gate sorting network for 3 elements, that's 6 possible inputs and (if I understand you correctly) 8 "solutions". That's small enough that you can draw the whole lot on a piece of paper and identify the interesting ones.

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor for the attention! I really appreciate it. Yeah thats what i meant. Those extra 2 gate configurations would still solve the problem. What if you have 2048 or 4096 and so forth? How they are distributed?

Comment: Ah, I've just seen [your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123334/5676). If this question is also about abusing sorting networks to generate permutations, it would help a lot to edit the question and make that clear. I've been assuming that you were trying to use the sorting network to sort. You may find [this thread](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5321/3131) on another site in the StackExchange network useful.

Comment: Hi @PeterTaylor well, the link is very helpful, and as you said that is indeed my primordial interest. But, i settled 4  using a sorting network (batcher's odd-even merge sort) instead. That is why i needed to know how the solutions distribute between the computational paths. Any insight on that matter is more than welcome